# Resume TimeMachine backup with Samba on RPi

Tags: samba, time-machine, raspbian

I backup my Mac using TimeMachine over Samba which is installed on my Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian Lite).

Everything was OK since a long time (I started this backup from macOS Big Sur and now I'm on Catalina). I have a file named MyMac.backupbundle on the network drive.

I had to reinstall my RPi and since that, it's impossible to resume the backups from the old file (MyMac.backupbundle). It only create a new file name MyMac.sparsebundle.

I just verify the old backup and it says : Time Machine has detected that your backups cannot be reliably restored. Time Machine must delete your existing backup history and start a new backup to correct this problem.

Is there a way to restore the backup history ?

Thanks.

Comment: I will try to clear my answer. My mac is on Catalina. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian 32bits and I use it to backup  my mac with Time Machine over samba. Everything was working great. I didn't touch anything on my Mac. I have reinstall my Rasberry with Raspbian 64bits. Since that, TimeMachine doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you solved your problem and also if you can help with mine :). Essentially I'm able to get TM running on Raspberry PI OS if using internal system folder, but it fails for folder in the external hard drive. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727030/samba-timemachine-folder-on-the-external-drive-doesnt-work

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't solved my problem and I had to restart my backups from the beginning... I will look at your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you went 'downhill' from Big Sur to Catalina, you will have to wipe your Time Machine & start over [or start a new one]. They are not backwards-compatible.

Up to Catalina, Time Machine backups relied on hard links on HFS+. From Big Sur onwards, they must be on APFS, which cannot use hard links. Big Sur will offer to upgrade your Time Machine, but Catalina cannot downgrade it.

Comment: My Mac was on Catalina and it works fine. I din't touch anything on my Mac, only on my RPi. I tried this https://gist.github.com/ahknight/dec202583a910756c6d9 and I have the error :
The volume Copies de sauvegarde Time Machine was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.

Comment: Catalina cannot read/write Big Sur Time Machine & Big Sur cannot read/write Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I can't understand is that everything worked perfectly before I change raspbian from 32bits to 64bits...

I didn't had any error message or a backup that fail. And now if I try to repair this disk I have a lot of overlapped errors. Even DiskWarrior can't repair it...

I think it's over...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't use the answer space for comments. You still haven't clarified your original issue - switching between Big Sur & Catalina will either fail to work or break the Time Machine volume. Unless you access it from the *same* OS that it was created on, it will not work.

Comment: Sorry @Tetsujin. I just add a comment to my original post to try to be more clear. Since that, I started to use DiskWarrior to check my TimeMachine backupbundle file. It's running since 24 hours and for the moment it says that there is more than 5000 overlapped files.